# How to fetch specific values from json in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table, in MySQL Version = 5.7

Table_1 <-

```
ID        Json
IR-1      {Json}
IR-2      {Json}
```

Sample Json String

```
{
  "flag": false,
  "resp": "RTUI",
  "mean": "r-2",
  "details": {
    "product": "IR JAD",
    "status": "failed",
    "datetime": "26/09/2017"
  }
}
```

I Want to fetch the field `resp`, `mean` and `status`, in below mentioned format. I'm using the below mentioned query but it works only to fetch the `status` in ["failed"] format.

```
select ID,
json_extract(Json, '$.*.resp') AS resp,
json_extract(Json, '$.*.mean') AS mean,
json_extract(Json, '$.*.status') AS status
from Table_1
where ID in ('IR-1','IR-2');
```

Required output:

```
ID     resp     mean      status
IR-1   RTUI     r-2       failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have `.*` for top-level properties.

Also, it would probably be better to specify the `details` property explicitly, than using a `wildcard` to access the nested `status` property.

```
select ID,
    json_extract(Json, '$.resp') AS resp,
    json_extract(Json, '$.mean') AS mean,
    json_extract(Json, '$.details.status') AS status
from Table_1
where ID in ('IR-1','IR-2');
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bWbuuN5WaXejN5W5eCbDRc/0)

Comment: Now I'm getting `mean` in "r-2" format but `resp` and `status` is still not coming.

Comment: My demo uses MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Is there a way to remove the double quote?

Comment: Use `JSON_UNQUOTE()`.